# Logic symbol $\forall$ before or after statement?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I have question about what is difference about two statements below.

$$\forall a,b,c, \ \ a+(b+c)=(a+b)+c $$

or

$$a+(b+c)=(a+b)+c , \ \forall a,b,c$$

I usaually see second in textbooks but my question is why not to write the first.

Comment: They are equivalent. The first allows for cleaner formulation of more complex statements but the second puts emphasis on the interesting part

Comment: To elaborate on what Bananach said: consider a statement like "for every $x$ there is some $y$ such that $x+y=0$." Quantifiers-in-front, this is easy to write: $\forall x\exists y(x+y=0)$. Quantifiers-in-back makes it weird: should we write "$\exists y(x+y=0)$, $\forall x$"? Or "$x+y=0, \forall x\exists y$"? Or ... Very quickly in mathematics, we wind up caring about multiple-quantifier statements (think e.g. about the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of *limits*), and for such statements the quantifiers-in-front form is far more understandable.

Answer (score 7):

Formally, the variant with quantifiers in front is the only correct well formed formula in first order logic. The second one is just the spoken form where "for all $a,b,c$" is said at the end, but written symbolically. I find that form very confusing potentially because it's unclear what the range of the quantifier is.

So only use

$$\forall a: \forall b: \forall c: (a+b) +c = a + (b+c)$$

to use your example. In this case the order of $a,b,c$ does not matter (they yield equivalent statements) so people also write in a shortened form:

$$\forall a, b, c: (a+b) +c = a + (b+c)$$

Comment: I would say that, in the first case (quantifiers in front), you are writing a logical formula. There *might* be a good reason for doing so. With the quantifiers in back, you are using those logical symbols as an ugly, deplorable, unnecessary kind of slang abbreviation for the English phrase "for all", kind of like writing "4" for "for" or "h8" for "hate". They are doing that in *books* now? Shame on the authors, publishers, editors and copy readers! $\Phi!$

Comment: @bof: I would upvote that as an answer, though I wish it would discourage the quantifier-in-back form more strongly.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a difference between the two statement, I prefer the first one with quantifiers declared at first.

Recall that when we have different quantifiers the order of them is very important.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in the two version of statements.

I have seen them both and as you noticed the second one is more commonly used than the first one.

Usually the condition is mentioned after the statement, but there is no difference.